# Send form information and an additional variable from HTML to PHP using a hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I have a form in HTML and I send their variables correctly to a PHP file. I have different containers with several options related to the geography. That means, the user can choose between show data at country/region/economic level. For knowing in the PHP which way of representation is filtering the user, I want to use an additional hidden input which value is 1,2 or 3 depending on the chosen way. I don't achive to change this hidden input value.

I use the following code:

```
<div class="popcountry">
        <div class="funcion" onclick="country_function();setGeo()">
        <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center;" id="geoselect">Country
        <input type="hidden" name="geo">
        </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="popmenu"  id="countrypopmenu">
        <br>

        <label class="container" style="text-align:center" id="selectControlcountry"> <b>Clear</b>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
            <span class="checkmark2" style="background-color:#F0FFF0"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="scrollbox2">
        <label class="container">Afghanistan
            <input type="checkbox" id="Afghanistan" name="country[]" value="Afghanistan" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">Albania
            <input type="checkbox" id="Albania" name="country[]" value="Albania" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
...

    <div class="popregion">
    <div class="funcion"  onclick="region_function();setGeo2()">
    <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center" id="geoselect">Region
    <input  type="hidden" name="geo">
    </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="popmenu"  id="regionpopmenu">
    <br>

    <label class="container" style="text-align:center" id="selectControlregion"> <b>Clear</b>
        <input type="checkbox"  id="selectall" />
        <span class="checkmark2" style="background-color:#F0FFF0"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">Africa
        <input type="checkbox" id="Africa" name="region[]" value="Africa" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">Americas
        <input type="checkbox" id="Americas" name="region[]" value="Americas" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
...
    <div class="popclass">
    <div class="funcion" onclick="class_function();setGeo3()">
    <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center" id="geoselect">Country Classification
    <input  type="hidden" name="geo">
    </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="popmenu"  id="classpopmenu">
    <br>

    <label class="container">Developed
        <input type="checkbox" id="Developed" name="classification[]" value="Developed" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">Economies in transition
        <input type="checkbox" id="Economies in transition" name="classification[]" value="Economies in transition" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
...
```

The functions are defined in javascript as:

```
function setGeo(){
        var geo =getElementByName("geo");
        geo.value= "1";
    }
    function setGeo2(){
        var geo =getElementByName("geo");
        geo.value = "2";
    }
    function setGeo3(){
        var geo =getElementByName("geo");
        geo.value = "3";
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem happening and what do you want?

Comment: When I do an echo of geo variable in PHP the variable is undefined. I want to change that variable's value depending on where the user clicks

Comment: If you add `id` on inputs as `geo` than you can select the elements. But, id should be unique.

Comment: So, you want that when user click on any `geo` this input will be changed? Not other `geo`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that there are multiple elements with name geo in the code that you posted. Either use a single element with name geo or use different names like geo1, geo2, geo3. 
getElementsByName(name) returns a collection of elements with the same name, so that furthermore, the reference by index is necessary. Like document.getElementsByName( 'elementname')[0];

Comment: It's the same name because I want to change that element value depending on where I do click. I mean, I named the three geo but the goal is to change geo to 1,2 or 3 depending on if you click on country, region or country classificaiton. If I use the same element I cannot difference if I had to change it to 1,2 or 3 no?

Comment: I recommend keeping one hidden variable, lets say geo and in function call pass value based on location setGeo(1), setGeo(2) and setGeo(3).

Answer (score 1):

```
function setGeo(){
    var geo = document.getElementsByName("geo")[0];
    geo.value= "1";
}
function setGeo2(){
    var geo = document.getElementsByName("geo")[0];
    geo.value = "2";
}
function setGeo3(){
    var geo = document.getElementsByName("geo")[0];
    geo.value = "3";

}
```

Comment: When I do:
$geo= htmlspecialchars($_POST["geo"]);
echo "$geo";

in the PHP I get undefined variable, so the value doesn't change when I click

Comment: yes, but you should remove multiple inputs with the name `geo`. So with our JS code, it will set for the first element only. And rest of the others will be having empty values and so you are not getting it in PHP code.

Comment: I did it. I'm trying to replicate this part of my code in jsfiddle. The code would have to return the value of geo when I click on submit, but I get an error. Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ac320qrw/7/

Comment: `document.getElementByName` is not a function. If it's a typo, `document.getElementsByName` returns an array. That code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you have to make "geo" input tag single also make change in the method instead of using 3 you can use single js method and pass parameter and this should work.

Please see the code snippet below

```js
function setGeo(geoVal) {

  document.getElementById('geodata').value = geoVal;
  console.log(document.getElementById('geodata').value);
}

/* blank functions, defined in order to repair the snippet */
function country_function() { }
function class_function() { }
function region_function() { }
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="geodata" name="geo">
<div class="popcountry">
  <div class="funcion" onclick="country_function();setGeo(1)">
    <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center;" id="geoselect">Country

    </h2>
  </div>
  <span class="popmenu" id="countrypopmenu">
        <br>

        <label class="container" style="text-align:center" id="selectControlcountry"> <b>Clear</b>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
            <span class="checkmark2" style="background-color:#F0FFF0"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="scrollbox2">
    <label class="container">Afghanistan
            <input type="checkbox" id="Afghanistan" name="country[]" value="Afghanistan" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    <label class="container">Albania
            <input type="checkbox" id="Albania" name="country[]" value="Albania" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label> ...

    <div class="popregion">
      <div class="funcion" onclick="region_function();setGeo(2)">
        <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center" id="geoselect">Region

        </h2>
      </div>
      <span class="popmenu" id="regionpopmenu">
    <br>

    <label class="container" style="text-align:center" id="selectControlregion"> <b>Clear</b>
        <input type="checkbox"  id="selectall" />
        <span class="checkmark2" style="background-color:#F0FFF0"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">Africa
        <input type="checkbox" id="Africa" name="region[]" value="Africa" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label class="container">Americas
        <input type="checkbox" id="Americas" name="region[]" value="Americas" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label> ...
      <div class="popclass">
        <div class="funcion" onclick="class_function();setGeo(3)">
          <h2 class="geography" style="text-align:center" id="geoselect">Country Classification
          </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="popmenu" id="classpopmenu">
    <br>

    <label class="container">Developed
        <input type="checkbox" id="Developed" name="classification[]" value="Developed" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">Economies in transition
        <input type="checkbox" id="Economies in transition" name="classification[]" value="Economies in transition" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label> ...
```

Comment: I tried but if I don't define a value in:
<input type="hidden" id="geodata" name="geo">
It doesn't return anything when I read it in the PHP. If I put an initial value =0 when I define the hidden input, it doesn't change, so it's like if it doesn't enter in the setGeo() function

Comment: You can add the name attribute to your HTML input element. You will just use the `id` to manipulate your field with JavaScript and the `name` attribute to ensure PHP receives the value of the field.

Comment: In your html if the "geo" value is not set then the element will not be found in php as it is not set or sent using post. So passing default value may help or In your php you can check if value is set using `isset()` method to validate it.

Comment: I set a default value =0 and my PHP read the 0 value, so the function setGeo() is not executed